# Extra argument 'onError' in call using RXSwift Single Trait

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm getting a very weird error using RXSwift. I'm calling a service that is a Single trait and when I just print the error my code compile without problem, but if I try to do something else in "onError", the code doens't compile. Someone had the same problem?

The piece of code that doesn't compile:

```
NetworkManager.shared.authorizeService(with: parameters)
            .subscribe(onSuccess: { [weak self] status in

                }, onError: { [weak self] error in
                    paymentAuthorizationFinishedWithError.onNext(APIResponseError.paymentAlreadyInProgress)
            }).disposed(by: bag)
```

The code that compiles:

```
NetworkManager.shared.authorizeService(with: parameters)
            .subscribe(onSuccess: { [weak self] status in

                }, onError: { [weak self] error in
                    print(error)
            }).disposed(by: bag)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift complier sometimes is very laggy. Especially when it comes to Rx. The problem is with this line

`self.paymentAuthorizationFinishedWithError.onNext(APIResponseError.paymentAlreadyInProgress)`

you forgot to add `?` since you're using `weak` reference:
`self?.paymentAuthorizationFinishedWithError.onNext(APIResponseError.paymentAlreadyInProgress)`